# Number of relations which are reflexive but not symmetric

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, relations

I have following doubt. Pls have a look
To find number of relations which are reflexive but not symmetric

———————————————————————————————

one way

$n(R-S)=n(R)-n(R \cap S) = 2^{(n^2-n)} - 1* 2^{n(n-1)/2} $———->(1 )

But if i think intuituively,
In relations matrix,

reflexive means all diagonal elements present
not symmetric means non-diagonal elements must be 1,0 or 0,1 or 0,0 for $a_{ij},a_{ji}$
It means non-diagonal elements have 3 possibibliees each
It means $1*3^{n(n-1)/2}$ ——————> ( 2)

But (1) and (2) are different. I know i made some mistake but i am not able to identify on my own. Pls help

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your second way of counting is incorrect. Because not symmetric **doesn't mean that all** off-diagonal pairs have to be either $(1,0)$ or $(0,1)$ or $(0,0)$. Some pair could be $(1,1)$ and still the relation could be non-symmetric.

For example, the following matrix represents a relation that is reflexive and NOT symmetric.
$$\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1\\0&1&1\\1&1&1\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: understood sir. thank you. How to think intuituively struture of NOT symmetric relation(instead of thinkng on the principle of inclusion-exclusion)

Comment: @NascimentodeCos Unfortunately many people think of not symmetric as anti-symmetric, which is INCORRECT. Note that for a relation to be not symmetric $\exists \, a,b \in A$ such that $(a,b) \in R$ but $(b,a) \not\in R$. Since the definition is based on "at least one pair" so all it takes to spot is (at least) one pair of entries $a_{ij}, a_{ji}$ (with $i \neq j$) in the matrix representation of the relation such that they are opposite.

Comment: sir what about asymmetric? can it be considered NOT symmetric. For assymetric relation, diagonal elements must be zero(ie., absent). Only NULL matrix is symmetric, assymetric, antisymetric, transitive right?

Comment: sir pls see above picture. Pls tell me is this correct?